# MySQL - Latest 3 orders

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

How to fetch latest 3 orders for a customer. Suppose, we only have one table Orders with 3 columns - Name, Price and Year.

```
Name  Price Year
Ram   40    2018
Ram   50    2017
Shaam 70    2021
Ram   30    2021
Shaam 20    2015
Ram   10    2013
```

Expected output:

```
Ram 30 40 50
Shaam 70 20
```

I want to fetch latest three orders for a customer, and if there are less than three orders then fetch accordingly (like Shaam).

Comment: Use ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY year) rn then use subquery and add a where rn <= 3

Comment: Could you please elaborate and explain.